# Making postgres backups from heroku database followers

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Previously you used to be able to create database dumps of database followers on heroku.

`heroku pgbackups:capture HEROKU_FOLLOWER_COLOR --expire`

It has stopped working recently.

If I `heroku logs --tail --ps pgbackups` I get

```
2013-03-07T17:27:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: dump_progress: start
2013-03-07T17:27:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_dump-9.2.1-64bit: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  cannot use serializable mode in a hot standby
2013-03-07T17:27:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: HINT:  You can use REPEATABLE READ instead.
2013-03-07T17:27:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: pg_dump-9.2.1-64bit: [archiver (db)] query was: SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE, READ ONLY, DEFERRABLE
2013-03-07T17:27:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: dump_progress:    0B
2013-03-07T17:27:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]:
2013-03-07T17:27:49+00:00 app[pgbackups]: dump_progress: error
```

Dumping from the main DATABASE_URL seems to work fine though.

Is this a recent change in heroku platform or am I doing anything wrong?
Also, is there a performance hit if I do a dump of the main database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backups from followers should be working again now. The failure was due to some changes we made to pgbackups (namely, adding the [--serializable-deferrable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgdump.html) flag for `pg_dump`). We missed that this wouldn't work on followers--sorry about that.

Thanks,

Maciek,

Heroku Postgres

Comment: What is the answer regarding performance when dumping the main database? Could you comment on that?

Comment: If you dump from the main database, it will definitely affect performance of it (more network and disk I/O, CPU, memory). Depending on your size and throughput, this may not matter at all, but it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-data-safety-and-continuous-protection#combining-physical-and-logical-backups for more details :)